# drawing a div element inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have this jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/VFZ4m/11/

when the user drop the div the same image should be created and drawn inside the canvas how can I do that ?

i tried this code but it's not functioning

```
$('#x').draggable();
$('#c').droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var img = ui.draggable;
    var ctxt =$("#c")[0].getContext("2d");
    ctxt.drawImage(img[0], 0, 0);
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using jQuery to draw a div background-image onto html canvas**

[image]

You can get a dropped div’s background-image URL like this:

```
var img = ui.draggable;
var bkURL=img.css("background-image");
bkURL=bkURL.substr(5).substr(0,bkURL.length-7);
```

Then you just new-up an image element with that URL as its .src:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    ctxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src=bkURL
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/WzHvJ/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style>
    body {
    padding: 20px;    
    }
    #x {
    border: 1px solid green;
        cursor: move;
        background:url('http://www.kidzui.com/images/layout/spaceship/star-orange-full.png') no-repeat;
        height:40px; 
        width:40px;
    }
    #x, #c {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    }
    #c {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid red
    }
</style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(function() {

      $('#x').draggable();
      $('#c').droppable({
          drop: function(event, ui) {
              var img = ui.draggable;
              var bkURL=img.css("background-image");
              bkURL=bkURL.substr(5).substr(0,bkURL.length-7);
              var ctxt =$("#c")[0].getContext("2d");
              var img=new Image();
              img.onload=function(){
                  ctxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
              }
              img.src=bkURL
              return false;
          }
      });

  });   // end $(function(){});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="x">&nbsp;</div>
    <canvas id="c" width="200" height="200">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is really a great answer you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

You can't access an image stored as a CSS background image like that - *there is no image element*.

It *does* work if the image is a real `<img>` tag within the `<div>`

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/DuCVG/1/

The (much harder) alternative would be to use `window.getComputedStyle()` to read the `background-image` CSS property from the element, parse it, and then create a brand new `Image` object that has the same source.